# Publish from Publishing Queue extension in SDL web 8.5

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

I am trying to run Publish from Publishing Queue extension on SDL web 8.5 but seems some JS related error when clicking on publish or unpublish from the queue. I downloaded the latest extension from [appstore](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/publish-from-publishing-queue-extension/632/) and followed the install note,

Any suggestion is there anything I am missing

[image]

Comment: Have you installed it from App store or from Alchemy site? On App store it is showing as supported till Web 8 while on Alchemy it is supporting Web 8.5. That might be an issue.

Comment: I've installed it from APP Store

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed it from App store or from Alchemy Web Store? On App store it is supported till Web 8 while on Alchemy Web Store it is supporting Web 8.5. That might be a reason of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We've found that we have some other GUI extensions deployed on same CMS and after making some changes in some other GUI extension the same eXtension that we download from App Store worked.- maybe that one was conflicting with the publish GUI extension.