# Republish from the publishing queue for Sites 9

Tags: publishing, sites-9

Please let us know if Republish from the publishing queue for Sites 9 work out of the box or do we need to install any extension if so how can we apply it for Sites 9.

Comment: welcome to tridion Stack exchange, you can refer to this link for more details https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19199/publish-from-publishing-queue-extension-in-sdl-web-8-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we don't have this out of the box , if you need to apply the extension you can download from this [link](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/publish-from-publishing-queue-extension/632/)

Comment: It *is* out of the box functionality for Sites 9.1 and higher, though.